# Web App WS-Federation Authentication not redirecting to Microsoft Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

My ASP.NET MVC 5 web app is not redirecting to the Microsoft login page (https://login.microsoftonline.com) and as far as I can see I have the configuration settings correct.

In the Global.asax.cs I have:

```
private void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider(object sender, RedirectingToIdentityProviderEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(IdentityConfig.Realm))
    {
        e.SignInRequestMessage.Realm = IdentityConfig.Realm;
    }
}
```

In the web.config I have the appSettings keys: ida:FederationMetadataLocation, ida:Realm, ida:AudienceUri, ida:ClientID, ida:Password:

```
<add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" />
<add key="ida:Realm" value="https://myapp.com" />
<add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://myapp.com" />
<add key="ida:ClientID" value="{client id}" />
<add key="ida:Password" value="{client secret}" />
```

AudienceUris in identityConfiguration:

```
<audienceUris>
    <add value="https://myapp.com" />
</audienceUris>
```

Issuer and realm attributes for the wsFederation:

```
<federationConfiguration>
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/wsfed" realm="https://myapp.com" requireHttps="true" />
</federationConfiguration>
```

In the Azure portal under **Authentication** I have **Web** as the platform with our site's URI.

Under **Expose an API** the **Application ID URI** is "*api://{client id}*".

I've read through the Microsoft documentation and nothing I've read sheds light on our issue.
From all the information I have found our configuration settings appear to be correct, though something is clearly not set correctly.
I've gone through the [Web app tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-tutorial-02-prepare-application?tabs=visual-studio) and [Configure Azure AD Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) documents.
I'm not finding anymore information about what else I can try.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you register the application in Azure AD.

For the App ID URI, enter https://<your_tenant_name>/, replacing <your_tenant_name> with the name of your Azure AD tenant.
In the web.config file, you need to add

ida:Tenant and replace the value with your AAD tenant name.
ida:Wtrealm and replace the value with the App ID URI mentioned above.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:Wtrealm" value="[Enter the App ID URI of your application https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/WebApp-DotNet]" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="[Enter tenant name, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]" />
  </appSettings>
```

There is an old reference sample to integrate Azure AD with WS-Federation which you can refer https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation